# Which is the better choice if a company owes you 17 dollars and you want to buy a 40 dollar lamp?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

An online company charges you the wrong amount on an item and owes you 17 dollars. You want to buy a 40 dollar lamp from the same company.

You are given 3 options: 1) You can keep the 17 dollar difference. 2) Give you a 60% discount on the 40 dollar lamp WITHOUT the 17 given back. 3) Give you **2** lamps for 40 dollars.

EDIT: Your son would like a desk lamp as well.

**Thought process**:

A 60% discount on the 40 dollar lamp would bring it down to 16 dollars, that I would pay (23.99 would be 60% of 40 dollars). I am a little stumped here because what I am thinking is that I would really only be paying 33 dollars total **(16 dollars from what I would pay + 17 dollars that they wouldn't give back).** If the 33 dollars is correct, the best option would be to buy 2 for 40 dollars.

Which option would be the best choice?

Comment: In order to evaluate option 3, we have to take into account whether the second lamp holds any value for you. Do you _need_ a second lamp? Do you even have somewhere to put it? If it will just collect dust in an attic, it's practically worthless.

Comment: LOL WE SAID THAT AT THE SAME TIME @Arthur

Comment: hey fast forward to 2100 sell that antique make it rain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a lamp and are willing to pay $ 40 for the lamp you have seen in the catalogue. You order it and pay for it.

Independently of this you may select between three goodies:

1. $ \$\  17$ in cash,
2. $ \$\ 24$  cashback on the lamp,
3. a second lamp for free.

Therefore you have to make up your mind between 2. and 3. The decision depends on wether you have some use for the second lamp.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see.

1. you get your money back, a \$0 gain
2. you would advantage \$24 so you are at a \$7 gain
3. you effectively gained \$40 so you are at a $23 gain

but the problem here is, do you even want a second lamp?

--

Update: Your son wants a lamp so you are getting the most effective bargain with choice #3.

Comment: I don't understand your answer.
For 1); how would I be at a loss if I gain \$17?

Comment: what do you mean? what does keeping the 17 dollar difference mean?

Comment: the way i interpreted it, you just do nothing about it

Comment: If I had \$0 in my bank account, and the company gave me the \$17 they owe me, my bank account would be +\$17. So I would be at a gain, not a loss.

Comment: so let's say i have \$80. and then i purchase a 50 dollar toy and get overcharged with \$67 and have only \$13 left. when i keep the difference, do i end with \$13, \$30, or \$47?

Comment: actually it doesn't matter anymore sigh